# Socket.io client : Websocket Connection failed : Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm building an web app(nodejs, port: xxx0) which interacts with an another app(nodejs, port:xxx5) which is serving as the socket.io server. My socket.io client code goes well in my web app. All works well in my local as the connections refers to the server as `io.connect('http://localhost:xxx5/')`

But the same is not working when i promote it to higher env as the connection string is as `io.connect('https://domainName/')`

When my app is trying to connect, I'm receiving the below error:
`websocket.js:112 WebSocket connection to 'wss://domainName/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

Am I missing anything?

When I try hitting the server(higher env) via socket.io tester, I get the response as `No sockets Found` and immediately then `An error occurred while reconnecting`

NOTE:. The server instances are registered in an api gateway in higher env.

#### Server.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const port = process.env.PORT || xxx5
const server = app.listen(port)
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
let ns = io.of('/namespace')

ns.on('connection', (socket) => {
logger.info('User connected')
socket.emit('messages', {new:2,[{title:'Hi'},{title:'Test'}]})
})
```

#### Client.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io(`https://domainName/namespace`, { transports:
['websocket'], rejectUnauthorized: true})
// const socket = io('http://localhost:xxx5/namespace', { transports:
['websocket'], rejectUnauthorized: true})
// above commented url is in local
socket.on('connect', () => {
logger.info("Connected")
})    
socket.on('messages', (data) => {
logger.info(`New messages : ${data.new}`)
})
socket.on('error', (error) => {
logger.error(`Error encountered : ${error}`)
})
```

Comment: whole code and not just some cherry pick ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running as a priveleged user? Any TCP/UDP socket less than 1024 is considered and IANA reserved port and required elevated priveleges to bind as a listening service.

Using cURL can also aid in providing the necessary handshake: (See reference of websocket handshake process here; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake)

`sh
$ curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: echo.websocket.org" -H "Origin: http://domainname " http://domainname`